# Writing data to AWS Aurora using StreamSets

Tags: amazon-web-services, streamsets, amazon-aurora

I have got one requirement where we have to write real-time data to AWS Aurora (PostgreSQL) using StreamSets Data Collector. I have never worked on StreamSets but I have learn that it's a data connector. I tried to search to get something on this topic but no luck. Any idea how StreamSets can be used to write data to Aurora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [StreamSets Data Collector](https://streamsets.com/products/sdc)'s [JDBC Producer destination](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Destinations/JDBCProducer.html#concept_kvs_3hh_ht) to write data to Aurora. Data Collector includes the JDBC driver required for PostgreSQL.